# How to synchronize host's and client's games in an online RTS game? (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, sockets, time, synchronization

So my project is an online RTS (real-time strategy) game (VB.NET) where - after a matchmaking server matched 2 players - one player is assigned as host and the other as client in a socketcommunication (TPC).

My design is that server and client only record and send information about input, and the game takes care of all the animations/movements according to the information from the inputs.

This works well, except when it comes to having both the server's and client's games run exacly at the same speed. It seems like the operations in the games are handled at different speeds, regardless if I have both client and server on the same computer, or if I use different computers as server/client. This is obviously crucial for the game to work.

Since the game at times have 300-500 units, I thought it would be too much to send an entire gamestate from server/client 10 times a second.

So my questions are:

1. How to synchronize the games while sending only inputs? (if possible)
2. What other designs are doable in this case, and how do they work?

(in VB.NET i use timers for operations, such that every 100ms(timer interval) a character moves and changes animation, and stuff like that)

Thanks in advance for any help on this issue, my project really depends on it!

Answer (score 0):

Timers are not guaranteed to tick at exactly the set rate.  The speed at which they tick can be affected by how busy the system and, in particular, your process are.  However, while you cannot get a timer to tick at an accurate pace, you can calculate, exactly, how long it has been since some particular point in time, such as the point in time when you started the timer.  The simplest way to measure the time, like that, is to use the `Stopwatch` class.

When you do it this way, that means that you don't have a smooth order of events where, for instance, something moves one pixel per timer tick, but rather, you have a path where you know something is moving from one place to another over a specified span of time and then, given your current exact time according to the stopwatch, you can determine the current position of that object along that path.  Therefore, on a system which is running faster, the events would appear more smooth, but on a system which is running slower, the events would occur in a more jumpy fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was one portion of the answer to the questions. I now realize I have to run the game in rounds, and let every player finish the round before continuing. However, I can use the stopwatch to calculate ping and performance to smoothen the experience for the users, through guessing performance and ping and letting each client perform like the worst to keep an even pace. I hope I can work this out or I'll return with more questions :) Thanks